# Should I use quotes in environment path names?

Tags: bash, shell, dotfiles

I'm in the process of cleaning up all my config files in an attempt to make them as readable as possible. I've been looking for a style guide on the use of quotes while exporting paths in, for example, a `~/.bashrc` file:

```
export PATH="/users/me/path:$PATH"
```

vs

```
export PATH=/users/me/path:$PATH
```

The Google [shell style](https://google.github.io/styleguide/shellguide.html#s5.7-quoting) guide suggests avoiding quotes for path names. In contrast, a lot of the popular dotfiles repos (such as Zach Holman's [here](https://github.com/holman/dotfiles/blob/75183cecb9d7c7c4a7cf5e9301cefffd2abf8ef7/system/_path.zsh)) use quotes. Are there any situations when it is an advantage to use quotes in the path?

Comment: I think you should use quotes when a directory name contains white spaces.

Comment: In this case, you must use quotes. Without quotes, the shell will perform word splitting and pathname expansion (and you certainly don't want that). Note though that `PATH` is certainly already exported, so you don't need to `export` it again. `PATH=/users/me/path:$PATH` (this time without quotes) is enough.

Comment: Google also has a requirement that file names in general, and directories in paths on particular, only contain characters from the portable filename character set.   That means only (Latin) alphabet, digits, underscore, dash, dot.  When that rule applies, it is safe to leave off the quotes.  It's only when people include bizarre characters in the directory name that quoting becomes a necessity.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

<sup>Tip of the hat to [@gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1815797/gniourf-gniourf) and [@chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) for their help.</sup>

**tl;dr**

**To be safe, double-quote: it'll work in all cases, across all POSIX-like shells.**

If you want to add a `~`-based path, *selectively* leave the `~/` *unquoted* to ensure that `~` is expanded; e.g.: `export PATH=~/"bin:$PATH"`.
<sup>See below for the rules of `~` expansion in variable assignments.</sup>
Alternatively, simply use `$HOME` inside a single, double-quoted string:
`export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"`

---

NOTE: The following applies to **`bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh`**, but NOT to (mostly) strictly POSIX compliant shells such as `dash`; thus, **when you target `/bin/sh`, you MUST double-quote the RHS of `export`**.<sup>[1]</sup>

- Double-quotes are ***optional*, ONLY IF  the *literal* part of your RHS (the value to assign) contains neither whitespace nor other shell metacharacters.**
- Whether the values of the *variables referenced* contain whitespace/metacharacters or not does *not* matter - see below.

  - Again: It *does* matter with `sh`, when `export` is used, so always double-quote there.

The reason you can get away without double-quoting in this case is that ***variable-assignment* statements in POSIX-like shells interpret their RHS *differently* than *arguments* passed to *commands***, as described in [section 2.9.1](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) of the POSIX spec:

- Specifically, even though *initial* word-splitting *is* performed, it is only applied to the *unexpanded* (raw) RHS (that's why you *do* need quoting with whitespace/metacharacters in *literals*), and not to its *results*.
- This **only applies to *genuine* assignment statements of the form

  `<name>=<value>` in *all* POSIX-like shells**, i.e., if there is *no command name* before the variable name; note that that includes assignments *prepended* to a command to define ad-hoc environment variables for it, e.g., `foo=$bar cmd ...`.
- **Assignments *in the context of other commands* should always be double-quoted**, to be safe:

  - With `sh` (in a (mostly) strictly POSIX-compliant shell such as `dash`) an assignment with `export` is treated as a *regular command*, and the `foo=$bar` part is treated as the *1st argument* to the `export` builtin and therefore treated as usual (subject to word-splitting of the *result*, too).
    (POSIX doesn't specify any other commands involving (explicit) variable-assignment; `declare`, `typeset`, and `local` are nonstandard *extensions*).
  - `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, in an understandable deviation from POSIX, extend the assignment logic to `export foo=$bar` and `typeset/declare/local foo=$bar` as well. In other words: **in `bash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, `export/typeset/declare/local` commands are treated like *assignments*, so that quoting isn't strictly necessary**.

    - Perhaps surprisingly, `dash`, which also chose to implement the *non*-POSIX `local` builtin<sup>[2]</sup>
      , does NOT extend assignment logic to it; it is consistent with its `export` behavior, however.
  - Assignments passed to `env` (e.g., `env foo=$bar cmd ...`) are also subject to expansion as a command argument and therefore need double-quoting - except in `zsh`.

    - That `env` acts differently from `export` in `ksh` and `bash` in that regard is due to the fact that `env` is an *external utility*, whereas `export` is a *shell builtin*.
      (`zsh`'s behavior *fundamentally* differs from that of the other shells when it comes to unquoted variable references).
- **Tilde (`~`) expansion happens as follows in *genuine* assignment statements**:

  - In addition to the `~` needing to be *unquoted*, as usual, it is also only applied:

    - If the *entire* RHS is `~`; e.g.:

      - `foo=~ # same as: foo="$HOME"`
    - Otherwise: *only* if *both* of the following conditions are met:

      - if `~` starts the string or is preceded by an *unquoted* `:`
      - if `~` is followed by an *unquoted* `/`.
      - e.g.,
        `foo=~/bin # same as foo="$HOME/bin"`
        `foo=$foo:~/bin # same as foo="$foo:$HOME/bin"`

**Example**

This example demonstrates that in `bash`, `ksh`, and `zsh` you can get away *without* double-quoting, even when using `export`, but *I do not recommend it*.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# or ksh or zsh - but NOT /bin/sh!

# Create env. variable with whitespace and other shell metacharacters
export FOO="b:c &|<> d"

# Extend the value - the double quotes here are optional, but ONLY 
# because the literal part, 'a:`, contains no whitespace or other shell metacharacters.
# To be safe, DO double-quote the RHS.
export FOO=a:$foo # OK - $FOO now contains 'a:b:c &|<> d'
```

---

<sup>[1] As @gniourf_gniourf points out: Use of `export` to *modify* the value of `PATH` is optional, because once a variable is marked as exported, you can use a regular assignment (`PATH=...`) to change its value.

That said, you may still *choose* to use `export`, so as to make it explicit that the variable being modified is exported.</sup>

<sup>[2] @gniourf_gniourf states that a future version of the POSIX standard may introduce the `local` builtin.</sup>

Comment: +1 for the reference to POSIX section 2.9.1 and an (indirect) explanation of why `FOO="${SOMEPATH}/bar.txt" ; cat ${FOO}` doesn't need to be (double) quoted even if `${SOMEPATH}` happens to contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristopherSchultz - you do need double quotes around `${FOO}`, though :)

Comment: Hmm... seems I'm out of luck when trying to build an env var which contains an optional parameter to a command, e.g. `[ predicate ] && OPTARG="-f ${MYPATH}/file" ; command ${OPTARG}`. Could you add an example to your answer which explains and/or handles this particular case?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz: This is really a separate question, so here's just a quick pointer: In `bash`, use an _array_ to store your arguments in, then pass that array in double quotes, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36814082/45375). The only portable solution is the - risky - use of `eval`.

Comment: Another thing is, if your key has a hashtag # and you don't quote, everything after the # will be interpreted as a comment and ignored!

Answer (score 16):

I used these answers above when setting environment path names in a docker .env file, and got bit. I'm putting this here for anyone else looking for how to define environment variables for docker.

Docker compose reads environment variables from an .env file that exists in the same folder that docker compose is run as stated here [https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file)

However instead of wrapping the value in quotes, docker compose needs the environment variable defined without quotes, unless the quotes are part of the value. Again, as stated in the url above

> There is no special handling of quotation marks (i.e. they will be
>   part of the VAL, you have been warned ;)

I was trying to set `NODE_PATH=./src` for absolute paths to work in a react app being deployed by docker, but had written it as `NODE_PATH="./src"`. This warning pulled me out of 4 hour rabbit hole.

Comment: Thank you for this! Took some debugging to figure out its including the quotation marks.

Comment: Well, I just experienced it in development after changing a config file. Crazy part is that production runs on that exact config file since days - with single quotation marks where docker-compose reads the .env file and everything is fine. Development no throws `unkown character '''` Now I am lost again in that developer's worst case scenario: It should not work, but it does.

Answer (score 4):

`test 123` is a valid path name on UNIX. Try

```
PATH=test 123
```

It will return:

```
123: command not found
```

Or even

```
export PATH=test 123
```

which will return

```
bash export: `123': not a valid identifier
```

Does it answer your question?

Honestly I would not follow such fourth party *style guides*. Although I'm astonished that even Google advertises such wrong advices.

I would follow:

- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/Bash-Beginners-Guide.html
- http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/
- https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html

(to be carefully extended)

Comment: TLDP's guides are also third party, and they are also biased in many ways, e.g., avoiding bashism at times when bashism is clearly superior. Anyway, shell scripting is extremely flexible (very simple example: do you use curly braces around variable names?), and in the end it usually boils down to one's own judgement.

Comment: I agree, however the Google *style guide* was wrong in this case. I've should called it 4th party.. let me change that

Comment: Well, it is wrong only if your literal part contains whitespace (which is bad practice in the first place) and you're confused enough to write down the assignment with the visible whitespace...

Comment: I should simply have explained that *word splitting* happens without quotes and what that means. I admit it is not my best answer ever.. If I'll have time later I'll give a proper explanation otherwise delete it.

Comment: You do realize expansion is different in assignment statements (with any preceding `declare` variant)?

Comment: See mkelement0's updated answer. It has an executable example. One thing I remembered wrong: in bash, it's okay even if assignment is preceded by a `declare` variant.

Answer (score 0):

Not path related, but same as in https://stackoverflow.com/a/48411223, I got bit as well in the context of docker compose.

I had a token env variable in my .env file, something like

```
MY_TOKEN="abc$123"
```

and got invalid login credentials errors because `MY_TOKEN` value was `abc&123` in the container. The actual token was much longer so it was quite difficult to spot the problem.

---

```
MY_TOKEN='abc$123'
```

did the trick.