# How do I store a command in a variable and use it in a pipeline?

Tags: bash, variables, grep, pipeline

If i use this command in pipeline, it's working very well;

```
pipeline ... | grep -P '^[^\s]*\s3\s'
```

But if I want to set grep into variable like:

```
var="grep -P '^[^\s]*\s3\s'"
```

And if I put variable in pipeline;

```
pipeline ... | $var
```

nothing happens, like there isn't any matches.

Any help what am I doing wrong?

Comment: As an aside: the fact that you're using a pipeline is incidental to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The robust way to store a ***simple* command** in a variable in Bash is to **use an *array***:

```
# Store the command names and arguments individually
# in the elements of an *array*.
cmd=( grep -P '^[^\s]*\s3\s' )

# Use the entire array as the command to execute - be sure to
# double-quote ${cmd[@]}.
echo 'before 3 after' | "${cmd[@]}"
```

If, by contrast, your command is **more than a *simple* command** and, for instance, involves pipes, multiple commands, loops, ..., **defining a *function*** is the right approach:

```
# Define a function encapsulating the command...
myGrep() { grep -P '^[^\s]*\s3\s'; }

# ... and use it:
echo 'before 3 after' | myGrep
```

---

**Why what you tried didn't work:**

```
var="grep -P '^[^\s]*\s3\s'"
```

causes the single quotes around the regex to become a *literal, embedded* part of `$var`'s value.

When you then use `$var` - unquoted -  *as a command*, the following happens:

- Bash performs word-splitting, which means that it breaks the value of `$var` into words (separate tokens) by whitespace (the chars. defined in special variable `$IFS`, which contains a space, a tab, and a newline character by default).

  - Bash also performs *globbing* (pathname expansion) on the resulting works, which is not a problem here, but can have unintended consequences in general.
  - Also, if any of your original arguments had *embedded* whitespace, word splitting would split them into *multiple* words, and your original argument partitioning is lost.

    - (As an aside: `"$var"` - i.e., *double-quoting* the variable reference - is *not* a solution, because then the *entire* string is treated as the command *name*.)
- Specifically, the resulting words are:

  - `grep`
  - `-P`
  - `'^[^\s]*\s3\s'` - *including* the surrounding single quotes
- The words are then interpreted as the name of the command and its arguments, and invoked as such.

  - Given that the pattern argument passed to `grep` starts with a *literal* single quote, matching won't work as intended.

Short of using `eval "$var"` - which is NOT recommended for security reasons - you cannot persuade Bash to see the *embedded* single quotes as *syntactical* elements that should be removed (a process appropriate called quote removal).

Using an *array* bypasses all these problems by storing arguments in individual elements and letting Bash robustly assemble them into a command with `"${cmd[@]}"`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation with my answer.

Comment: @sjsam: I appreciate the feedback. It later occurred to me that `$(echo "$var"`) is effectively no different from the OP's own approach (just `$var`) - the treatment by the shell is ultimately the same.

Comment: the idea with function i like the most, tnx!

Answer (score 3):

What you are doing wrong is trying to store a command in a variable. For simplicity, robustness, etc. commands are stored in aliases (if no arguments) or functions (if arguments), not variables. In this case:

```
$ alias foo='grep X'
$ echo "aXb" | foo
aXb
```

I recommend you read the book Shell Scripting Recipes by Chris Johnson ASAP to get the basics of shell programming and then Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins when you're ready to start writing scripts to manipulate text.

Comment: While using an _alias_ is an option, the fact that alias expansion is by default _disabled_ in scripts makes this solution awkward: you'd have to run `shopt -o expand_aliases` in your script first.

Comment: @mklement0 what makes you think the OP wants to put this in a script?

Comment: While you can certainly define variables and even functions in an interactive shell, they're _typically_ used in a script. Whatever the OP's specific use case may be, that aspect wasn't specified, so it's worth pointing out that in scripts aliases won't get expanded by default

Comment: My aliases are defined in .env or .profile files and I just use them in my interactive shell. I don't use them in any scripts and I have no need to define them in a script. YMMV I suppose.

Comment: To summarize: ++ for your alias approach to cover use in _interactive_ shells; between your answer and mine we now have both use cases covered (interactive use vs. use in a script). I'd suggest showing the alias definition with the OP's exact command, however, to highlight potential quoting troubles.