# Should path be included in double quotes?

Tags: shell

In a shell script, should I not include directory path in double quotes, e.g.

```
export PROJECT=/NFS/private/release/dir1
```

or should I include in double quotes, e.g.

```
export PROJECT="/NFS/private/release/dir1"
```

Comment: I'm not sure parentheses is the word you mean to use...

Comment: @LioraHaydont Sorry! Fixed!

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in this case.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I use quotes in environment path names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318499/should-i-use-quotes-in-environment-path-names)

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in this particular case, but it's recommended to assign a string  value within double-quotes. `a="string"`. http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/quotingvar.html