# Install scala to Apple Silicon

Tags: java, scala, apple-silicon

I am trying to install scala in MacBook with M1 chips. I have had Zulus javaJDK 15.0.2 installed. I have previously used this page to install home-brew: [Getting a warning when installing homebrew on MacOS Big Sur (M1 chip)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65487249/getting-a-warning-when-installing-homebrew-on-macos-big-sur-m1-chip)

But when installing scala by `brew install scala`, I get the following message:

Error: Failed applying an ad-hoc signature to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib:
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: replacing existing signature
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/15.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/MacOS/libjli.dylib: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed

==> Caveats
...
...
If you need to have openjdk first in your PATH, run:
echo 'export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

For compilers to find openjdk you may need to set:
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/include"

For the system Java wrappers to find this JDK, symlink it with
sudo ln -sfn /opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk/libexec/openjdk.jdk /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk.jdk

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBUiQ.jpg)

Despite of this message, I can already run scala script from vscode. So should I worry about the path issue in the message above ? Thanks !

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. A hint for the future: when asking a question, never use a screen shot, unless your question is about a GUI. Always paste in text. Text is searchable, screen shots aren't. The purpose of Stack Overflow isn't just to get your question answered, it's to accumulate searchable questions and answers, because that helps everyone and makes the world better.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience caused, I will pay attention to it next time. But I have lost the terminal with the message, and I have just noted some lines. I have added them to the description. Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

I successfully installed it using [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/) so that is worth a try.

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
```

Start a new shell or `source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"`

```
sdk install java
sdk install sbt
sbt compile
```

Really fast on an M1 with 16GB RAM :)

Comment: Mac Book Pro/Air/Mini?

Comment: Mac Mini. But the Pro seems to have about the same performance, presumably because the ARM chip is low power and doesn't need thermal limiting.

Comment: Still pondering Mac Mini vs Air, is the Air significantly slower?

Comment: I think the Air is slower, so if you don't need to use it as a laptop then Mini is best :)

Comment: I installed zulu version of java. "sdk install java 15.0.2-zulu" then installed sbt and scale. it worked perfectly.

Comment: for me (M1 Mini), SDKMAN won't install the right version for the chip even if zulu is specified. SBT fails at runtime

Comment: Just installed on a new M1 mini and it still works for me :)

Comment: To install scala with specific version: ```sdk install scala 2.11.12```