# Trouble trying to install scala on Mac M1

Tags: scala, installation

I would like to get started with scala. I have a Mac M1 computer and so I follow the instructions [on this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/scala/comments/q1acoy/comment/hfdknjq/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) which seems to be the same as in the [official website](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/). So it do

```
$ brew install coursier/formulas/coursier
$ cs setup
```

for which the output is (output of `cs setup`)

```
Checking if a JVM is installed
Found a JVM installed under /Users/johnsmith/Library/Caches/Coursier/arc/https/github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk8-binaries/releases/download/jdk8u292-b10/OpenJDK8U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_8u292b10.tar.gz/jdk8u292-b10/Contents/Home.
  Should we update ~/.profile, ~/.config/zsh/.zprofile, ~/.bash_profile? [Y/n] y

Checking if ~/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin is in PATH
  Should we add ~/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin to your PATH via ~/.profile, ~/.config/zsh/.zprofile, ~/.bash_profile? [Y/n] y

Checking if the standard Scala applications are installed
  Found ammonite
  Found cs
  Found coursier
  Found scala
  Found scalac
  Found scala-cli
  Found sbt
  Found sbtn
  Found scalafmt
```

Apparently this should install the following

s itself, to further manage your Scala environment

**scala-cli**, a convenient tool to compile / run / package Scala code

**scala**, the Scala REPL

**scalac**, the Scala compiler

**sbt** and sbtn, the sbt build toold

**ammonite**, an enhanced REPL for Scala

**scalafmt**, the Scala code formatter

but I cannot acces any of them. When I do for instance

```
scala -version
```

I get

```
zsh: command not found: scala
```

Comment: It's possible that the PATH environment variable was changed in one of those dot files but not in the current shell. Kill the shell and restart it and see if the commands can now be found.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk, I tried to close the shell and reopen but it still didn't work

Comment: When it asked "Should we add ~/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin to your PATH via ~/.profile, ~/.config/zsh/.zprofile, ~/.bash_profile? [Y/n] y", did you answer yes? And have you looked at the PATH settings in those files?

Comment: I gave [one way of installing it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66464892/7662670) in an answer to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66464412/install-scala-to-apple-silicon) and the answer seems to work for other people. But the question was closed so it might not be visible and probably can't be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: Okay so I think I found my issue [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/901403/zsh-not-sourcing-zprofile). Since it exported the path in `.config/zsh/.zprofile` and this is only sourced when openening a login shell, just opening a new shell didn't source the `.config/zsh/.zprofile` so didn't export to the path. However if I do `su johnsmith --login` it will source it (but `su johnsmit` wont, weird since both seem to be logins for me). In the end I just exported the path in `.zshenv`. I guess the distinction between login shells and non-login shells are not clear to me^^

Answer (score 3):

Simple do this

```
brew install scala
```

Comment: Got exactly the same problem and this worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
source ~/.zprofile
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

To go more in depth let's talk about **why** each answer above works because assuming you installed Scala correctly on MacOS you probably used [Scala's short download guide here](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/).

So what are these answers trying to accomplish? Well they are both [`brew install scala`, `source ~/.zprofile`] trying to add the command `scala` to the terminal environment's `PATH` so when you actually try to execute the command it'll find it and not throw a `zsh: command not found: scala` error.

#### So what should I do and what's going on?

Firstly you should only use the command that is given on [Scala's official website](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) and not try anyone's random instructions. As of October 2023 this is the command that they provide. I recommend just going to the [official site](https://www.scala-lang.org/download/) in case this changes in the future.

```
brew install coursier/formulas/coursier && cs setup
```

What we are doing is setting up `Coursier` first which is a dependency manager for Java and Scala projects. This is also used to install `Scala`.

So part one is installing `Coursier` via `brew install coursier/formulas/coursier` and part two is installing `Scala` and other tools you may need via `cs setup`. So there are two commands separated by the `&&`.

#### Why doesn't `scala` work after I install and configure everything?

Well this is likely due to it not being on your `PATH` for your current terminal session. You should have gotten a prompt to add something to your path like below and you should have answered `Y` to it. Otherwise you **will** have to do this manually. To find out what you need to put there you can hopefully look at the history on the terminal and find that. Otherwise you should be able to find it somewhere but I don't have the time to find that.

```
Checking if ~/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin is in PATH
  Should we add ~/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin to your PATH via ~/.profile, ~/.zprofile? [Y/n] Y
```

This is adding `~/Library/Application Support/Coursier/bin` to the `PATH` via your `~/.profile` and `~/.zprofile`. So if you do `nano ~/.zprofile` you should be able to look in that file and see that there.

Typically on new terminals it reexecutes these files and runs those commands to add those variables to your `PATH`.

#### What is the fix?

You should go back and see if you added it to the path. If so look to see where it added it and just do `source theCorrectPath` and it should add it as a variable to your terminal.

You don't and shouldn't do `brew install scala`. It isn't necessary since you already have it on your system then you might end up with multiple versions of Scala installed, and it might not be clear which one is being used when you run `scala` in the terminal. So why does this work too? Homebrew (`brew`) automatically updates the system PATH so you can run the installed software from the terminal. `Coursier` usually asks for permission to do this but essentially accomplishes the same thing.