# Error making API request when using Vault secrets

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault, nomad

I am following [this tutorial](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/getting-started-first-secret?in=vault/getting-started) but I don't know why I am getting these permissions errors when I run some vault commands

```
  vault kv put secret/hello foo=world
    Error making API request.
    
    URL: GET http://127.0.0.1:8200/v1/sys/internal/ui/mounts/secret/hello
    Code: 403. Errors:
    
    * permission denied
```

For further info...

```
vault status
Key             Value
---             -----
Seal Type       shamir
Initialized     true
Sealed          false
Total Shares    1
Threshold       1
Version         1.8.4
Storage Type    inmem
Cluster Name    vault-cluster-fc4492f9
Cluster ID      87956902-532d-dcfd-5e9a-9f1d36207ef4
HA Enabled      false
```

And the version of my the vault package

```
vault --version
Vault v1.8.4 (925bc650ad1d997e84fbb832f302a6bfe0105bbb)
```

I have already exported the Token and the address, so I have no clue what to do next to solve the issue. Can anyone help me out? Thanks in advance.

---

### UPDATES

From the UI I do have access to http://127.0.0.1:8200/ui/vault/ but still having the same issue from the CLI. I even tried vault auth login but nothing changes.

Comment: How did you export the token, and what OS are you on? Try it again, it looks like it did not work.

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20 and I took the token printed by the console when you use vault server -dev "Root Token"

Comment: The command I use for exporting the token is 
export VAULT_DEV_ROOT_TOKEN_ID=s.l6Rb88CZvfgsKxKOxDNh1ONC
But I also tried with
 export VAULT_TOKEN=s.l6Rb88CZvfgsKxKOxDNh1ONC

Comment: As [the tutorial you linked to shows](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/getting-started-dev-server?in=vault/getting-started#starting-the-dev-server), you need to surround the token with quotes: `export VAULT_TOKEN="s..."`.  Did you do that?

Comment: hey, I feel so dumb now, it was that, the quotes with VAULT_TOKEN. Add the answer and I will upvote it. Thanks man

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You must use quotes around the token when exporting it:

```
export VAULT_TOKEN="s..."
```

[Reference in the tutorial](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-dev-server?in=vault%2Fgetting-started#set-environment-variables).

Comment: I had a env variable with VAULT_TOKEN with old value causing the problem. After updating the env variable VAULT_TOKEN its working fine... Thank you

Comment: Actually you don't need to use quotes.

Comment: @its.me.adam - [in `/bin/sh` you do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33318499/should-i-use-quotes-in-environment-path-names).  In other shells, it doesn't hurt.  I assume that's why [the Vault docs show using quotes](https://developer.hashicorp.com/vault/tutorials/getting-started/getting-started-dev-server?in=vault%2Fgetting-started#set-environment-variables), to ensure maximum portability.  If you want to share why you think it isn't necessary you might help future visitors more than just downvoting will.

Comment: If the OP is on Ubuntu 20, I assume they are using bash.